# Translation of coercive function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

Let $X$ be a Banach space. If we consider a coercive function as a function defined in the following way: $P: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ is coercive iff $\exists f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}: \lim\limits_{s \rightarrow +\infty}f(s) = +\infty$ and $\langle P(u),u \rangle \geq f(\Vert u \Vert)\Vert u \Vert$. In other words, $P$ is coercive means that $$\lim\limits_{\Vert u \Vert \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\langle P(u),u \rangle}{\Vert u \Vert} = +\infty$$

Would it the follow that the translation of $P$ defined as $P_{T}(u) := P(u+w)$ for some $w \in X$, is $P_{T}$ then also coercive?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: On a side node, you can use `\|` to typeset $\|$ instead of `\Vert`.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I will consider Hilbert spaces. I think this example can be generalised to Banach spaces.

Take a closed hyperplane $H$ in $X$, fix $w\in H^\bot$ and now take a non-trivial linear continuous function $g:X\to \Bbb [0,+\infty)$ such that $\ker g = H$ and consider a construction $$P(u) =|g(u-w)|u .$$ Then it is obvious that this function is coercive. On the other hand, $\langle P(u+w),u\rangle=0$ whenever $u\in H$, therefore the translation is not coercive.

Comment: @TZakreviskiy Thanks for your response. What assumptions of $P$ do you think would make it true? Are you famaliar with Sobolev spaces?

Comment: @Alex I think some sort of uniformity in $u$ will make it happen: $\exists R>0:\ \inf_{\|u\|>R}\langle P(u),u/\|u\|\rangle>0$.

Comment: @Alex as per Sobolev spaces - of course, I'm familiar with them. If they are Hilbert spaces, then the same counterexample works. If they are not, I think, we still can build some example basing on Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Are you familiar with the book 'Nonlinear partial differential equations with applications' by Tomas Roubicek? My question was inspired by a result in this book. If you have a chance please view the post 'Nonlinear partial differential equations with applications' by Moses.

Comment: Maybe the fact that $A$ is pseudomonotone in addition to being coercive allows the translation to be coercive.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this book, so I can't really help you or Moses here. If $A$ is pseudomonotone - maybe it helps, give it a try.